# Add hours based on country of origin

Tags: r, countries

So I have a column displaying the country of origin from each Facebook post.I also have the time creation of the post.What i want to do is to add 3 hours for every Arabian post. Then i want to add 5 hours for Russian posts.Let's say i have 12 countries with 12 different time zones that need to be added.

The language is R.

```
allCountries <- c("Arabia" , "Argentina", "Brazil", "Global", "India","Malaysia",
                          "Mexico","Poland","Sweden","Turkey","MaxTurkey","Ukraine","US")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
(df <- data.frame(datetime=rep(Sys.time(), 3), origin=c("arabian", "russian", "us")))
#              datetime  origin
# 1 2016-05-04 11:27:52 arabian
# 2 2016-05-04 11:27:52 russian
# 3 2016-05-04 11:27:52      us
offset <- c("arabian"=3, "russian"=5)
```

Then

```
transform(df, datetime=datetime + offset[origin]*60*60)
#              datetime  origin
# 1 2016-05-04 14:26:12 arabian
# 2 2016-05-04 16:26:12 russian
# 3                <NA>      us
```

or

```
transform(df, datetime=datetime + ifelse(origin %in% names(offset), offset[df$origin]*60*60, 0))
#              datetime  origin
# 1 2016-05-04 14:27:52 arabian
# 2 2016-05-04 16:27:52 russian
# 3 2016-05-04 11:27:52      us
```

Comment: My dates come in this format 20/4/2016 13:12 in excel.